# Wordpress REST api, how to seach custom field values

Tags: wordpress, rest

I'm using the Wordpress REST api to get all my post data, and using a frontend framework to display them. I've created several post types, who each have different custom fields (I created the fields using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin and the acf-to-rest-api plugin to add the fields to the json output).

Now I'm trying to use Wordpress' search function to search through custom field values, using a url like this:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/articles?search=test
```

Currently, only the body text and title values are being used in the search, not the custom fields.

I've found a plugin to allow the search to include custom field values ( https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-fields-search/ ), but when I installed it, nothing changed. I don't think the plugin works with the rest API.

Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Really late reply, but for people stumbling upon this post I have an answer to this problem:

```
add_action(
'rest_api_init',
function () {
    register_rest_field(
        'search-result',
        'excerpt',
        array(
            'get_callback' => function ( $post_arr ) {
                return $post_arr['excerpt'];
            },
        )
    );
  }
);
```

In the callback you can pretty much return anything you want, does not have to be specifically taken from the `$post_arr`variable.